# How do I create a total_sales column in power bi when I have price_per_unit and quantity_ordered

Tags: powerbi, dax

This has got to be the simplest question ever, but after seeing a half a dozen sites I can't figure it out.  How do I create a total_sales column in Power BI when I have a price_per_unit column and a quantity_order column?

All I want to do is make a column that says "price_per_unit * quantity_ordered" but all I get are errors about the column not existing, or the SUM calculation wanting a measure, or some such thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **calculated column** (not a measure) on the table those two columns are part of and definite is like

```
Total_Sales = Table1[price_per_unit] * Table1[quantity_ordered]
```

[image: New column]